# How to upload pdf file as multi part form data in alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have to upload pdf file as multi part form data.
I read [Alamofire/Usage.md(Uploading Data to a Server)](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#uploading-data-to-a-server)

So I write below code.

```swift
extension ViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard let url = urls.first else { return }
        print(url) // file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/69C5B45A-AA29-46D2-909C-2A1A5A68C10F/tmp/com.test.test-Inbox/D5100_EN.pdf
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            print(data) // 10899227 bytes
            AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "pdf")
            }, to: "https://myurl.com")
                .responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response) // message = "Required request part 'file' is not present"
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

But it was filed.
How can I upload pdf file as multi part form data in alamofire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need  to specify the `mimeType` :

```
multipartFormData.append(pdfData, withName: "pdfDocuments", fileName: "pdf", mimeType:"application/pdf")
```

**Updated**

According to the error you must understand that server is expecting a pdf with name "file"

try this:

```
 multipartFormData.append(pdfData, withName: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType:"application/pdf")
```

Comment: still failed. Is there a wrong way to get data from UIDocumentPickerDelegate?

Comment: sorry for late answer. it just same error. response is `message = "Required request part 'file' is not present"`

Comment: Thankyou, Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify `MimeType`. Try updating your request to

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "name", fileName: "fileName", mimeType: "application/pdf")
}, to: "https://myurl.com")
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response) // message = "Required request part 'file' is not present"
}
```

Comment: still failed. Is there a wrong way to get data from UIDocumentPickerDelegate?